# Help understanding a paragraph in the book ‘Conceptual Mathematics‘

Tags: category-theory

I’ve always planned to try and learn some Category Theory since doing an MSc in computation over 30 years ago. I’ve now retired so have some time to spend learning things that are not immediately useful for work, so was finally able to start on ‘Conceptual Mathematics’ (one of the few books that doesn’t require you to be a trained mathematician - I’m an Engineer). All was OK till I got to page 150 but I simply can’t visualise what the author is talking about in the paragraph that starts “An abstract structure type often arises from a particular example as follows...” I probably just need to let this one little section go and move on but it offends by sense of rigour not to even follow this section.

---

An abstract structure type often arises from a particular example as follows. Suppose $\mathcal A$ is a small family of objects and maps in a category $\mathcal X$, with the domain and codomain of any map in $\mathcal A$ being in $\mathcal A$. Let each object $A$ in $\mathcal A$ be considered as the name of "A-shaped figures" and each map $\alpha$ in $\mathcal A$ be considered as a name $\alpha^*$ of structural map. The domain of $\alpha^*$ is the codomain of $\alpha$, and the codomain of $\alpha^*$ is the domain of $\alpha$. Then every object $X$ of $\mathcal X$ gives rise to an $\mathcal A$-structure whose $A$-th component set is the set of all $\mathcal X$-maps $A\to X$ and wherein for each $B\xrightarrow{\alpha}A$ the structural map on these figures has for all $x$
$$\alpha_X^*(x)=x\circ\alpha$$

> **Exercise 29:** Every map $X\xrightarrow fY$ in $\mathcal X$ gives rise to  a map in the category of $\mathcal A$-structures, by the associative law.

For example, the abstract notion of *graph structure* can be identified with the concrete diagram $\mathcal A$ of graphs below

[image]

because for any graph $X$ the arrows in $X$ may be identified with the graph maps $A\xrightarrow xX$, the dots in $X$ with the graph maps $D\to X$, and the source of $x$ is then $s_X^*(x)=x\circ s$; for any graph map $X\xrightarrow fY$, the associativity $f(xs)=(fx)s$ then substantiates, inside the category itself, the fact that $f$ preserves sources:
$$s_Y^*\circ f=f\circ s_X^*$$

---

Can anyone help, either by explaining what the author means or pointing me to some alternative text that explains the same material in a different way?

Comment: Hi Mike. You'd have better luck getting someone to answer this question if you quoted the relevant section; that way an answerer doesn't need to have a copy of this book to answer.

Comment: I believe this is referring to the notion of a 'presheaf category', and to the 'yoneda embedding'.

Comment: The category of graphs is an example of a presheaf category. The yoneda embedding identifies two very special graphs in the category of graphs.

Comment: @Mike It may be also helpful to include the page 149 as well, as it appears to explain more about “structure” and “structural maps”.

Comment: This kind of construction is explained in a lot of detail in the book [Generic Figures and their Gluings](https://marieetgonzalo.files.wordpress.com/2004/06/generic-figures.pdf) by Reyes et al. Just the first few pages of that might help you in your understanding of this passage.